# How can you add to network_security_config from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an app  I get some values from a webserver per OkHTTP, which works and it displays it on MainActivity. Now I want to add those recieved values to `network_security_config.xml`.

For simplicity sakes, I set a String in MainActivity to be equal to `YZPgTZ+woNCCCIW3LH2CxQeLzB/1m42QcCTBSdgayjs=`

Now I want this string to appear in my `network_security_config.xml` at `VALUE_I_WANT_TO_ADD`. How do I do this? Could I maybe use jdom for this ?

**`network_security_config.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">google.com</domain>
      <pin-set expiration="2020-01-01">
  <pin digest="SHA-256">MbZtXtN6X71CNe/UJzKFH0UGnPWGux5/zo5BRaJpkvI=</pin>

<pin digest="SHA-256">VALUE_I_WANT_TO_ADD</pin>
      </pin-set>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: You cannot modify the network security configuration at runtime.

Comment: Manifest is immutable, i think, you can't change it on runtime

Comment: @CommonsWare I know that the xmls in res cant be changed, but how can I add/update something then?

Comment: You cannot modify any file in the resources folder at runtime, do you want to save something for using it later?

Comment: "but how can I add/update something then?" -- you can't. There is no API for you to change the network security configuration, either in the form of the file or in the form of the in-memory representation of that data.

Comment: @VivekSingh I mean once I got that string in the xml, for the next time I run it I want to use that one, or at least have it added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it appears that you want to save your string for a later use, so you can use `SharedPreferences` to save the `String` for later use.

```
final String TAG = "some final text";
sharedPref = new SharedPreferences();
sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(TAG,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

    editor.putString("key","your_string");
    editor.apply();
```

Later on, you can retreive your string from `SharedPreferences` when you run your app again as follows

```
    String value = sharedPref.getString("key","default_value");
```

Comment: for later use, how can I add it to the xml?

Comment: Where is your xml file located?

Comment: the xml file is located at Androidwebviewer\app\src\main\res\xml\network_security_config.xml

Comment: You can't modify any file of the android app source file structure at run time of the app by any means. You have to move to any other method to solve your problem.

Comment: Cheers, I will try another method instead of this. Thanks for the advice