# HTTPS - Is Web Request and response are got Encrypted?

Tags: java, android, http, https, ssl-certificate

Am making webservice calls to HTTPS server from an android application. Below is the code snippet, with which am able to make web service calls successfully and getting response.

My Question is, do we need to perform any additional step to encrypt data before making call to HTTPS server? 
Because, from android profiler am able to see all my Web Requests in plain text format. My understanding is that request will gets encrypted before making HTTPS call.

[image]

```
     public static WebServiceResp makeWebServiceCall(String XML, String urlPath) throws IOException{
    //Code to make a web service HTTP request
    String responseString = "";
    String outputString = "";
    String wsURL = urlPath;
    URL url = new URL(wsURL);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    HttpsURLConnection httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection)connection;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


    //System.out.println(XML);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[XML.length()];
    buffer = XML.getBytes();
    bout.write(buffer);
    byte[] b = bout.toByteArray();
    // Set the appropriate HTTP parameters.
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                                String.valueOf(b.length));
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);


    OutputStream out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    //Write the content of the request to the outputstream of the HTTP Connection.
    out.write(b);
    out.close();
    //Ready with sending the request.

    //Check the status
    int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    Log.d(TAG, "makeWebServiceCall: "+"Processing Status: "+status);


    BufferedReader in;
    if (status <= 200) {
        //Read the response.
        Log.d(TAG, "makeWebServiceCall: Getting Input Stream");
        InputStreamReader isr =
                new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream());
        in = new BufferedReader(isr);
    }else{
        //Read the response.
        Log.d(TAG, "makeWebServiceCall: Getting Error Stream");
        InputStreamReader isr =
                new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getErrorStream());
        in = new BufferedReader(isr);
    }

    //Write the SOAP message response to a String.
    while ((responseString = in.readLine()) != null) {
        outputString = outputString + responseString;
    }
        Log.d(TAG, "makeWebServiceCall: WebServiceResponse " + outputString);
        //Parse the String output to a org.w3c.dom.Document and be able to reach every node with the org.w3c.dom API.
        Document document = Utils.parseXmlFile(outputString);
        //NodeList nodeLst = document.getElementsByTagName("GetWeatherResult");
        // String weatherResult = nodeLst.item(0).getTextContent();
        //System.out.println("Weather: " + weatherResult);

        //Write the SOAP message formatted to the console.

    WebServiceResp webServiceResp = new WebServiceResp();
    webServiceResp.setDocument(document);
    webServiceResp.setStatus(status);
    return webServiceResp;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  If you're sending it to an https website, the encryption is done as part of the protocol.  You don't need to do any additional work.

Comment: But from Android studio, am able to see all my requests which my app is making in Plain XML format? Is this something Android studio can decrypt when Mobile is connected with Debug mode.

Comment: WHere in android studio?  What are you looking at?  It isn't encrypted until its sent to the OS's socket subsystem deep inside the HTTP stack.

Comment: Added Image of decrypted form of Web Request which i can see in plain text

Comment: YEah, that's taken at a higher level in the stack, before encryption/after decryption.  It you sniff the traffic at the router it will be encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

No. The encryption that you see is on the network layer. The client which initiates the https call see what was sent and what was received. That is how https works.

When you look at chrome browser's network tab, you see what was sent and what was received. Now this is not a security problem, https is more about you doing things which make its difficult for anyone between the network to eavesdrop your data.

Now if you still want an additional level of security you can use certificate pinning

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning

https://medium.com/@appmattus/android-security-ssl-pinning-1db8acb6621e

[How can you add to network_security_config from MainActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075325/how-can-you-add-to-network-security-config-from-mainactivity)

So in this technique you basically say that the certificate hash that you expected is to have this content. And then if someone uses a trusted proxy with trusted CAs on the system, even after generating a valid certificate for the given domain the connections will not be established.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is transparent to your application, all of the magic happens between Transport Layer(so it calls 'Transport Layer Security'), you may imagine encrypted telegrams in the old days, generals tell telegrapher messages in plain text, and telegrapher send them in encrypted form(maybe use some kind of codebook), anyone who didn't have the same codebook can't decrypt the message easily, and anyone who uses telegrams didn't care about the codebook(or even known about it, except those telegraphers on both side of the 'Transport Layer').

Answer (score 1):

The encryption/decryption is done by built-in network client module provided by OS. So you needn't worry about it.

You can view plain texts with some client tools as they know exactly what they are sending/receiving. E.g. chrome developer tool. (Actually they don't care about encryption/decryption either).